At a cell in googlesheet1 i need to get background color value of a cell (using cellcolor function) in googlesheet2 (using importrange function)
At a cell in one googlesheet1 i need to get background color value of a cell (using cellcolor function or any other custom function) in another googlesheet2 (using importrange function or other function). tried =cellcolor(importrange("Gsheet2 url","cell address"),"fill") but failed. this is not working. can any body help me out please. i need function not a manual method to go to sheet2 etc...
i could succesfully use vlookup , index-match etc functions along importrange to do some tasks in a spreadsheet based on data in other spreadsheet but not able handle cellcolor / getcolor etc customised functions to getcolor of a cell , those work perfect on cells within any sheet of same spreadsheet but not on a cell in seperate spreadsheet
